# SCCM - Querying Device compliance via powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm, baseline

Any SCCM experts out there, can help on what I am doing wrong. I am trying (via PowerShell) to get a list of devices that are not compliant. We have a PowerShell script setup which performs the compliance check on the clients. And within the GUI, I can see the list of compliant and non compliant client device names.

I am struggling to get a list of these devices though via powershell. I can see the total number non-compliant, but see no way to export the list of the devices names themselves.

So this works to get the count of devices compliant for example, but how do I get a list of the device names themselves? Am Totally Stumped..

```
Get-CMBaseline -Id 17551554 | Get-CMBaselineDeployment  | Get-CMBaselineDeploymentStatus -StatusType NonCompliant
```

Thanks in advance, and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into your post which helped me realize my error.  However your part I solved for applications a long time ago (so use it there too, just change the select statement :)).

Just add  `| Get-CmDeploymentStatusDetails | Select assetname`

You'll get your devices.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).